# set_time_limit does not work to create a timeout

Tags: php

I have a problem on PHP.
I want to create a timeout error after a fixed delay (stop an execution after a maximum time). I use set_time_limit for that.

I use this script for the test :

```
<?php
set_time_limit(1);

sleep(10);
echo "END";
```

But this page does not display a Timeout error. It displays "END" !

Comment: [Read here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php#115057): _Both `set_time_limit(...)` and  `ini_set('max_execution_time',...);` won't count the time cost of `sleep`,`file_get_contents`,`shell_exec`,`mysql_query` etc..._

Comment: Oh, right. I guess the only way to manage the counter and the error itself